# Has this formula for $G_{k}:=\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}p_{n+k}-p_{n}$ been conjectured?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-constellations

I give [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132973/would-the-following-conjectures-imply-lim-inf-n-to-inftyp-nk-p-n-ok-lo) a heuristics that suggests that the quantity $\displaystyle{G_{k}:=\liminf_{n\to\infty}p_{n+k}-p_{n}}$ should be approximately equal to $k(1+H_{k})$, where $H_{k}$ is the $k$-th harmonic number. It seems that whenever $k$ doesn't divide $G_{k}$ then we have $$\dfrac{G_{k}}{k}-(1+H_{k})=-\dfrac{k+\delta_{k}}{M_{k}}$$ where $M_{k}$ is the least common multiple of the first $k$ positive integers, and $\delta_{k}$ is the number of integers $m\lt k$ such that $M_{m}=M_{k}$.

My question is: has this already been conjectured? If so, could I get some references? Of course, I also welcome any insight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Hardy-Littlewood prime tuples conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html) implies that $G_k$ equals the smallest diameter of an admissible $(k+1)$-tuple. In particular, it implies that $G_{10}=36$ (cf. [here](http://math.mit.edu/~primegaps/)).

Your conjecture implies for $k>3$ that
$$ G_k>kH_k+k-\frac{2k^2}{M_k}>kH_k+k-3.$$
In particular, it implies that $G_{10}>36$.

So your conjecture contradicts a widely believed old conjecture.

**P.S.** I have not checked if the OP's first display yields an integral value for $G_k$. If not, then it is false for the trivial reason that $G_k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

As proved in the polymath 8b paper found here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.4897v4.pdf we have the bounds:

$$(\frac{1}{2}+o(1))k\log(k) \leq H(k) \leq (1+o(1))k\log(k)$$

where $H(k)$ is the diameter of the smallest admissible $k$-tuple.  The Hardy-Littlewood prime-tuples conjecture  implies $G_{k}=H(k+1)$.  See Theorem 3.3 in the paper for an even better upper bound.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not falsify the OP's conjecture. See also my response.

Comment: These bounds are only conditional, if I understood well.

Comment: @Sylvain: Right.  I've corrected my post.

Comment: @GH: It doesen't falsify the OP's second conjecture, but it is a step towards *verifying* his initial guess that $G_k$ should be approximately $k*H_k$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: Yes, but this was already told to him by Terry Tao in an earlier post (see the OP's earlier questions).

Comment: @GH: I was not aware of this fact, as (apparently) the thread you are talking about has not yet been directly linked on this page.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: The thread I meant is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185354/what-would-be-the-consequences-of-displaystyle-lim-inf-n-to-inftyp-nk-p

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question, but apparently Zhi-Wei Sun conjectured that for all $k\gt 4$ one has $0\lt \dfrac{G_{k}}{k}-H_{k}\lt \dfrac{2+\gamma}{\log k}$ (where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant) which contradicts my own conjecture.